derivative of Logistic Regression (sigmoid)
I am having difficulty figuring out, why I get different answer from the professor. we are tasked with finding the deriative of the logistic regression cost function with the sigmoid function:
$$ L(w│D)=-\frac{1}{m} ∑_{i=1}^{m}[y_i log(σ(w^T x_i))+(1-y_i )log(1-σ(w^T x_i)) ] $$
after some calculations I got to the solution:
$$ -\frac{1}{m} ∑_{i=1}^m[y_i-σ(w^T x_i )] x_i $$
but the professor answer is
$$ -\frac{1}{m} ∑_{i=1}^m[σ(w^T x_i ) - y_i] x_i $$
its flipped...
I looked at many other calculations, some of them ended up like mine and some like the professor. additionally chatGPT says that both forms can be used "In the context of logistic regression, both forms are used in different contexts."
  I dont understand how both forms could be interperted in a simmilar manner, since our goal is to minimize the cost function, every minus sign is improtant. 

I dont think my problem is with calculations, but someone asked me to upload my work:


Please [edit] to show your work. Also, a number of worked answers can be found using a search https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=logistic+regression+derivative+answers%3A1

Usually the simplest, most reliable way to check the sign of a result is to apply the formula to a simple, easily calculated example.  Another reliable way when you are computing derivatives is to plot the original function and inspect it to see whether the sign of your putative derivative agrees with the direction of the slope in the graph.  The question of checking your work is of no interest here on a statistics site; possibly the math site would find it on topic but likely would appreciate evidence of the kinds of simple checks I just described.

Something that confused me here is the expression $\sigma(w^Tx_i)$. But what is the function $\sigma$? The minus sign can happen there in the definition of $\sigma$. I know that the logistic formula is often expressed as  $y = (1-e^{-x})^{-1}$, and for convenience, I sometimes use  $y = (1-e^{x})^{-1}$. That can create the problems you got.

I agree with others, that figuring out the error with a minus sign is not much of interest here. But something inside of me wants to consider this question as 'confusion' and likes to try search for 'enlightenment'. (as it is Friday afternoon, I am currently unable to do this)

A possible source of difference in a minus sign is the cost function Why do we minimize the negative likelihood if it is equivalent to maximization of the likelihood?
